# Command to check if a variable inside of a string exists

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot

I need a user to input two numbers to form a range and make an error message if one or both numbers are not inputed ,or a letter is inputed.
What i do now is

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['set'])
def handle_message(message):
    if (message.text == '/set'):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'put in a range')
    elif  message.text.split()[1].isdigit() :
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "something")
    elif message.text.split()[1].isdigit() == False:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Only letters!')
```

But the problem is that if a user doesn't put anything in the  2nd variable i get a syntax error. I tried using

```
except IndexError:
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Only letters!')
```

but that returns a SyntaxError.
What i am looking for is a way to check if `message.text.split()[2]` exists(has any value) and then check if it is a digit.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting a `syntax` (!) error when the user does not enter anything? That seems unlikey.

Comment: `if len(message.text.split()) > 1 and message.text.split()[1].isdigit():`?

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing that you're running into is a legitimate SyntaxError -- you can't use `except` without `try`.  See usage below.

The second thing you're going to run into is an IndexError -- what if you look for a second parameter when less than two exist?

The first is to look before you leap:

```
if len(message.text.split()) > 1:
    # do check
```

the other is to catch the TraceBack:

```
my_messages = [1]
try: 
    my_messages[2]
except IndexError:
    print("length was too short to continue checking!")
```

Where you're getting string inputs, you should also be sure to strip extra whitespace, as it may trip you up:

```
message = '1234 '
message.isdigit()
# False!
```

remove whitespace that would force this to be a string:

```
message = message.strip()
message.isdigit()
```